# nux3でcomposableの値を取得したい

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

`components/Heading1.vue`はレイアウトに組み込まれています。
`pages/page.vue`から`composable/useOperation.vue`を経由して`components/Heading1.vue`のタイトルの値を変更したいのですが`タイトル初期値`のまま変わりません。

`pages/page.vue`から`h1Text`を呼び出すと`表示したいタイトル`が取得できます。
他のコンポーネントからの変更は受け取れないのでしょうか？
`components/Heading1.vue`の`h1Text`の宣言をrefにしてみてもダメでした。

``

layout/default.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
v-app
  Heading1
  slot
</template>
```

pages/page.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
NuxtLayout
  | ページ本体

</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useOperationInsurance } from '~/composables/useOperation'

const { setHeading } = useOperationInsurance()
const title = '表示したいタイトル'
setHeading(title)
</script>
```

components/Heading1.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
.heading
  h1 {{h1Text}}
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useOperationInsurance } from '~/composables/useOperation'

const useOperation = useOperationInsurance()
const { h1Text } = useOperation
</script>
```

composable/useOperation.vue

```
import { reactive, Ref, toRefs } from 'vue'
import { Operation } from '~/types/operation'

export const useOperationInsurance = (): {
  h1Text: Ref<string>
  setHeading: (title: string, breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[]) => void
} => {
  const state: Operation = reactive({
    h1Text: 'タイトル初期値',
  })

  const setHeading = (title: string) => {
    state.h1Text = title
  }

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    setHeading,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setHeadingを外に出さないといけないようです。

```
import { reactive, Ref, toRefs } from 'vue'
    import { Operation } from '~/types/operation'
    
    const setHeading = (title: string) => {
        state.h1Text = title
    }
    
    export const useOperationInsurance = (): {
      h1Text: Ref<string>
      setHeading: (title: string, breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[]) => void
    } => {
      const state: Operation = reactive({
        h1Text: 'タイトル初期値',
      })
    
      
    
      return {
        ...toRefs(state),
        setHeading,
      }
    }
```